# Android AlarmManager doesn't cancel identical Intents

Tags: android, serialization, alarmmanager

For the last two days, I have been trying to get AlarmManager to cancel my previously set Alarms, for some reason I can't get it to work.

I have googled the problem, and the most common solution was to keep track of the old intents, because only with those, they are cancelable.

In order to tackle this, I decided to create my own Intent class, which is Serializable.

I then saved the Intent classes into a "Intent.ser" file, and recalled those to cancel my alarm.

**SerUitvalIntent.java**

```
public class SerUitvalIntent extends Intent implements Serializable
{

private String klas;
private int delay;
private Boolean uitvalBuzz;
private Boolean algemeenBuzz;

public SerUitvalIntent(Context context, Class<?> class1)
{
    super(context, class1);
}

public void setBundle(Bundle b)
{
    klas = b.getString(someClass.KLAS);
    delay = b.getInt(someClass.DELAY);
    uitvalBuzz = b.getBoolean(someClass.UITVALBUZZ);
    algemeenBuzz = b.getBoolean(someClass.ALGEMEENBUZZ);
}

public Bundle getBundle()
{
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putBoolean(someClass.UITVALBUZZ, uitvalBuzz);
    b.putBoolean(someClass.ALGEMEENBUZZ, algemeenBuzz);
    b.putString(someClass.KLAS, klas);
    b.putInt(someClass.DELAY, delay);
    return b;
}

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8289838097824161902L;
}
```

**someClass.java**

```
public static void schedule(Context context, long delay, Bundle data, Boolean startup)
{
    DataHandler dHandle = new DataHandler(context, false);
    final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    SerUitvalIntent oldIntent = dHandle.getAlarm();

    if(oldIntent != null)
    {
        oldIntent.putExtra(BUNDLE, oldIntent.getBundle());
        oldIntent.putExtra(FROMUI, false);
        Bundle b = oldIntent.getBundle();
        Log.i("AlarmManagerUitval", "Cancelled " + b.getString(KLAS) + "." + b.getInt(DELAY) + "." + b.getBoolean(UITVALBUZZ) + " alarm");
        final PendingIntent oldPending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, oldIntent, 0);
        //Cancel latest alarm
        alarm.cancel(oldPending);
    }


    final SerUitvalIntent intent = new SerUitvalIntent(context, UitvalService.class);
    intent.setBundle(data);
    dHandle.setAlarm(intent);

    intent.putExtra(BUNDLE, data);
    intent.putExtra(FROMUI, false);

    final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Log.i("AlarmManagerUitval", "Started " + data.getString(KLAS) + "." + data.getInt(DELAY) + "." + data.getBoolean(UITVALBUZZ) + " alarm");
    long time;

    if(startup)
    {
        time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }
    else
    {
        time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+delay;
    }
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, time,delay, pending);
}
```

My Logcat shows identical data when the alarms are set and cancelled (Log.i() shows identical data), but somehow it doesn't cancel.

**Logcat Data**

```
05-26 14:21:00.108: I/AlarmManagerUitval(26041): Started v4.60000.true alarm
05-26 14:21:00.178: I/UitvalService(26041): updating: v4
(...)
05-26 14:21:30.227: I/AlarmManagerUitval(26041): Cancelled v4.60000.true alarm
05-26 14:21:30.237: I/AlarmManagerUitval(26041): Started h4.60000.true alarm
05-26 14:21:30.307: I/UitvalService(26041): updating: h4
(...)
05-26 14:22:30.526: I/UitvalService(26104): updating: v4
05-26 14:23:30.244: I/UitvalService(26104): updating: v4
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up :P

I saved the data I wanted to send along in the alarm, and recreated a generic Intent everytime I wanted to cancel the previous alarm.

I then recalled the saved data on the Intent that was called by the alarm.

If somebody somehow finds the correct answer to this problem, I'll still be interested to know. :)

Wampie